# MySQL utf8_general character mapping table

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

From what I understand, when MySQL compares a string stored in utf8_general collation, it first converts it's characters to their ASCII equivalents. In other words ḩ = h, ţ = t, ā = a, í = i, etc...

Is there a mapping table which I could use to implement similar comparison function in php or JavaScript? I know there are alternatives in PHP such that iconv but their transliteration is slightly different, e.g. í = 'i.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a PHP extension that does what you want: http://pecl.php.net/package/translit
HOWEVER, internally, it's only calling iconv, so probably of no real use to you. 

I am not aware of any (universal) standalone PHP or JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to normalise your string to Unicode Normal Form D (which puts diacritical marks in a separate character to the base letter), and then remove all characters with the unicode ‘combining diacritical’ class.

See [normalizer_normalize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) to get normalisation in PHP. I'm not aware of a solution for JavaScript: there's nothing built in and you'd have to force the client to suck down some large Unicode character data tables.